# Creating android views in background

Tags: android, webview, android-service, android-3.0-honeycomb

Due to the restrictions of my app, we need to preload a view with a set of views (Buttons, Images, Video, WebViews...) outside the main UI thread, so we can create a thumbnail of the whole container view.

We are discussing how convenient is this. Is it ok to CREATE a view in an android service? (Not adding it to the main activity)
We are also having trouble creating a WebView in the service in order to create the thumbnails. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks for your time